# In which book Nietzsche says "es denkt in mir"?

Tags: nietzsche

I'm watching an online class on YouTube about Nietzsche, and there was this phrase.
In which book Nietzsche says "es denkt in mir"?

Comment: See [Friedrich Nietzsche: Es denkt](https://blog.zeit.de/schueler/2013/11/20/friedrich-nietzsche-es-denkt/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[F. W. J. von Schelling](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schelling/), [On the History of Modern Philosophy (Zur Geschichte der neueren Philosophie, probably 1833–4)](https://books.google.it/books?id=y6Jhy3v6HzIC&pg=PA48), English tranls., page 48 :

> It thinks in me, thinking goes on in me, it is the pure fact, in the same way as I can say with equal justification : "I dreamed", and "It dreamed in me". [See [German text](https://books.google.it/books?id=Djs99N7vt7IC&pg=PA82).]

Nietzsche discusse "It thinks" into [Beyond Good and Evil (1886), § 17](https://books.google.it/books?id=LHTKIY4Id1AC&pg=PA17).